# Electrical breakers question

Tags: electrical

Does each hot wire in a double pole breaker carry the breaker's rated amperage or does each wire split the amps? For example, if a double pole breaker  is rated at 50 amps, does each hot wire carry 50 amp protection or 25?

Answer (score 1):

Both conductors can carry the maximum current. However, since it can either be a 240V circuit or a 120/240V circuit, it can seem a bit confusing. At no time will you be able to draw more than the max current, but it is possible to have the maximum current on both conductors.

In all cases, both ungrounded conductors will have to be rated to carry the maximum current.

Also note that the conductors only carry the current drawn by the loads attached. So the conductors will carry anywhere from 0 to the maximum current, depending on the demand of the loads.

Answer (score 0):

A main breaker rated @ 100 Amps can have each pole itself carrying up to 100 Amps.

#### The Illusion

If both poles are drawing 100 Amps then the total Amps being consumed and passed through at the meter is 200 Amps. But a multimeter *will read 100 Amps*, not 200 Amps.

The double pole breaker is not rated at 200 Amps because the double pole breaker is designed to protect each pole independently and is designed to simultaneously shut off both poles if either exceeds 100 Amps.

#### Illustration

To help illustrate the concept we have to understand that power/watts does not change in regards to the amount of voltage/amps supplied.

A 12,000 Watt appliance will require 100 Amps @ 120 volt, or 50 Amps x 2 (concurrently) @ 240 volts.

A double pole breaker is basically two independent 120 volt sources delivering  concurrent power.

#### Nomenclature

When speaking of over current protection ie the breaker, we don't add up the concurrent poles, but take the total kilowatts and divide that into the voltage.

If the voltage were 3 phase then we'd factor in 1.73 (square root of three) to the equation.

Comment: I've seen this type of explanation before and it seems backwards and misleading. From what I understand, you will not measure 200A anywhere on the line in your example scenario. Rather, you're drawing 100A@120V on one pole and returning 100A@120V on the other pole. Because of the phase difference, you'll measure 100A@240V across both poles, not 200A@120V.

Comment: The only thin that is going to "read" the 200 Amps is the meter.  What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: No part of your statement about reading 200A makes sense to me, which is why I expressed my confusion at this explanation. My meter reads kWh, not amps.

Comment: And how do you get kW ? By Amps x Volts.  Sorry it doesn't make sense.  What about is confusing?

Comment: I understand the relationship between watts, amps, and volts. But by your logic it seems correct to say that standard US residential circuits are wired 1800A 1V, which would not be correct, would it? I think your answer would be clear if you were to remove the sentence, "Theoretically if both poles are drawing 100 Amps the total Amps being consumed and read at the meter is 200 Amps, Watts=Volts*Amps."

Comment: You seem to be confusing a very basic concept with something not so basic.  And I can see why.  Breakers do not read the total combined Amps from both poles.  But never the less, the meter will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27583/discussion-between-kris-and-rob).